# Android json image from database

Tags: android, json

I have a database that stores some data and images.
I want to display each image with it's data in a list-view on Android.
I am being able to show the data but I do not know how to display the image with it.
I would highly appreciate it if a solution could be provided using just android code as I'm pretty new to php.

Comment: Usually image is not sent/stored in json. Can you give more details about database? Also php usually is not applicable for android

Comment: The database has images stored as blobs.

Comment: Is it local android db?

Comment: Do you getting image-url OR complete image, in response from server??

Comment: I don't get the url. It's just a blob that I'd like to get from the database and decode.

Comment: You could add image data as base64 in your json. This will work but this is really not nice implementation

Comment: can you show us sample JSON with correct image data?